# Mapped array with the resulting strings separated by carriage return

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I return strings from a nested array separated by a carriage return?

```
var store = [
    [ 'deli', 'over roasted turkey', 10.50 ],
    [ 'bakery', 'sliced sourdough', 8.00 ],
]
```

What I've tried. I'm sure I need to use join but can't seem to figure out the right placement.

```
function list(store) {
    return store.map(function(item) {
    return item.toString();
})}

console.log(list(store))
```

result should look like this

```
  'deli, over roasted turkey, 10.50',// separated by carriage return  \n
  'bakery, sliced sourdough, 8.00'
```

Comment: _"`,// separated by carriage return  \n`"_ Are you expecting the comma at end of first line to be within result?

Comment: The result is ambiguous, can you clarify (1) if the result is a string or a string array, (2) if the result is to literally contain single quotes, (3) clarify the newline requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the body of your `list` function to:

```
return store.map((item) => {
    return item.toString();
}).join('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you are looking for [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
var store = [
  ['deli', 'over roasted turkey', 10.50],
  ['bakery', 'sliced sourdough', 8.00],
];

console.log(store.map(function(a) {
  return "'" + a.join(', ') + "'"; // I guess `a.toString()` works too
}).join(',\n'));
```

`Array#join` concatenates all elements of the array with the passed delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var store = [
    [ 'deli', 'over roasted turkey', 10.50 ],
    [ 'bakery', 'sliced sourdough', 8.00 ],
]
  
function list(store) {
    return store[0].join(",") + "\n" + store[1].join(",");
}

console.log(list(store));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function list(store) {
  return store.map(function(row){return row.join();}).join('\n');
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two elements in `store` array `.map()` is not necessary. You can use `Array.prototype.join()`, `String.prototype.concat()` with parameter `",\n"` in concatenate comma character `,` and newline, and second element of `store` with `.join(" ")` chained.

```
var res = store[0].join(" ").concat(",\n", store[1].join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you could use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
var store = [['deli', 'over roasted turkey', 10.50], ['bakery', 'sliced sourdough', 8.00]],
    pre = store.map(a => `'${a.join(', ')}'`).join(',\n');
  
document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = pre;
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join each item from the store by `,` (Make sure to have a space after the comma) and then join each item's string by `,\n` like so

```js
var store = [
  [ 'deli', 'over roasted turkey', 10.50 ],
  [ 'bakery', 'sliced sourdough', 8.00 ],
];
            
function list(store) {
  return store.map(item => item.join(', ')).join(',\n');
}
            
console.log(list(store));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is a little ambiguous, I think you want an array containing two strings only:

```
[
  "deli, over roasted turkey, 10.50",
  "bakery, sliced sourdough, 8.00"
]
```

In doing this problem, I found a few challenges:

1. Convert numbers 10.50 and 8.00 and preserve two decimal places you need toFixed().
2. Convert an array of strings to a comma delimited string, you need join()
3. Converting a 2x3 array to a 2x1 array, you need map. (i.e. you're keeping the original number of arrays).

The code you had was extremely close, here's my answer:

```js
var store = [
    [ 'deli', 'over roasted turkey', 10.50 ],
    [ 'bakery', 'sliced sourdough', 8.00 ],
]

function list(s) {
    return store.map(function(item) {
        return [item[0], item[1], item[2].toFixed(2)].join(", ");
    } )
}

console.log(list(store));
```